# .gnupgp in .hplip in my home directory Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, pgp

Why is there a `.gnupgp` subdirectory in `~/.hplip`? I do have a `~/.gnpgp` directory, but why is one in the `.hplip`? The contents are different. 
 Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l ~/.hplip/.gnupg`?

Comment: janos@acerlinux:~$ ls -l ~/.hplip/.gnupg
total 20
-rw------- 1 janos janos 4407 Sep 30 11:41 pubring.gpg
-rw------- 1 janos janos 4407 Sep 30 11:41 pubring.gpg~
-rw------- 1 janos janos    0 Sep 30 11:41 secring.gpg
-rw------- 1 janos janos 1200 Sep 30 11:41 trustdb.gpg
janos@acerlinux:~$

Comment: Sorry, I did not succeed formatting the text